# How to insert a new div in Ext.window

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, sencha-cmd

I need to create a new `div` which will wrap the exist-ExtJS made one. I aim to insert a CSS propert *(background image)* for this new `div`.. Here is scenarios:

```
<!-- First div is ExtJS made-->
<div class="x-window">

    <!-- I want to create this one to wrap image inserted div below! -->
    <div class="newOne" style="text-align: center;">

        <!-- This div is ExtJS made as well! -->
        <div class="x-window-header" style="background-image: url('Icon.png');></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I've used the upper `div` which is ExtJS made and name of `x-window` but it did not applied `text-align: center;` property. I've tried align to center within same `x-window-header` div element but it did not applied as well!

What is the way to create non-ExtJS made div?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Display an image vertically aligned in the center of the window header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add css use **cls** confid and giv class name.

if you want to add image in header do following things:-

**first step:-**

```
'cls':'className'
```

**second step:- in your css file**

```
.className .x-window-header{
   background-image: url(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change Ext.window.Window 'renderTpl' property.